# Rails paperclip - using with files already on my system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm using paperclip to manage attachments. This works fine for when the user uploads a file, but we have a feature where a user can select from an image already on our system in a seperate directory from paperclip.

Once they've selected that image from our system, how do I get paperclip to process and handle the image from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paperclip has an adapter for `File` objects, so assuming you got the full path for the file from user input, you can create a new `File` object then pass it to the attachment attribute in your destination model and save everything normally.

```
 file = File.new(file_path_from_user_input)
 user.attachment = file
 user.save
```

Comment: Yup, this was it. Thanks for the help, much appreciated.